# derivative of log and reciprocal

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

I am searching for a function $f(x)$ with the following property

The derivative $$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{f(x)})$$ is in opposite sign with the $$\frac{d}{dx}(ln(\frac{1}{f(x)}))$$ i-e either of two is positive or negative .

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question but for any negative function $f$ the two expressions you have are opposite in sign.

Comment: I need to have a positive f(x)

Comment: Since $\ln$ is increasing, $\ln(g(x))$ is increasing whenever $g(x)$ is increasing and decreasing whenever $g(x)$ is decreasing.  So their derivatives can't have opposite signs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left(\log\frac1{f(x)}\right)'=\frac{\left(\dfrac1{f(x)}\right)'}{\dfrac1{f(x)}}$$ so that to achieve opposite signs you need ${f(x)}<0$. But then the logarithm is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a strange problem...
I assume you are looking for a differentiable function `f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+`, to have a well-defined `ln(1/f)`. 
But then,

```
(ln \circ 1/f)’=\frac{1/f}{(1/f)’},
```

which has the same sign as `(1/f)’`since `f`takes positive values.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac d{dx}\left(\frac1{f(x)}\right)=-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}$$ $$\frac d{dx}\left(\ln\left(\frac1{f(x)}\right)\right)=-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$ So,
$$\frac d{dx}\left(\frac1{f(x)}\right)=-\frac d{dx}\left(\ln\left(\frac1{f(x)}\right)\right)\implies -\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$ If this has to be true for any $x$, I do not see anything to be possible.

Comment: Hi Claude, there is a shortcut, no need to develop in full :-)